# Python (OOP) list append error

Tags: python, class, oop

in need of a little insight. I have the following python code:

```
>>> class invader:
...     def __init__(self):
                // list
...             self.parameters = []
...
...     def parameters(self):
...             param = self.parameters
...             param.append('3')
... 
>>> invade = invader()
>>> invade.parameters()
```

Running this in terminal produces the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Don't use `parameters` as both a member and property name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem is using the same name for your attribute and method, rename `self.parameters` to `self.param` and use `self.param` in your method:

```
class invader:
   def __init__(self):
     self.param = []

   def parameters(self):
      self.param.append('3')

invade = invader()
invade.parameters()
print(invade.param)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the last line:

```
invade.parameters()
```

You are effectively using the list `parameters` as a function. (Note `()` at the end)

Do a

```
print invade.parameters
```

will let you see the content of the list and remove the runtime error

Answer (score 1):

Both your method and attribute contain the same name `parameters` so you can do as follows here:

```
def parameters(self):
    self._parameters.append('3')
```

It's a common to encapsulate attributes with underscores, especially with methods of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Your method and attribute contain the same name `parameters`. Since data attributes will override method attributes with the same name. So `invade.parameters` is list, not function. You should rename your function, such as `append_parameters`.
If you want to call `parameters` function, you can try this way:`invader.parameters(invade)`.But it's not recommended